# Rails - Creating multiple home#index pages with same html but different variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, seo

For SEO purposes, I'd like to be able to use the same HTML template in my `paint#index` file to create multiple urls with different `@seo_title` attributes.

For example:

My HTML index page (located on app/views/paint/index.html.erb):

```
<% @seo_title = "Red Paint Colors" %>
<h1> PAINT COLORS </h1>
<ul><% @paint_colors.each do |p| %>
  <li><%= p.name %> - <%= p.color_family %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

And my routes file:

```
get "red-paint-colors", to => "paint#index"
```

This makes the url: ww.mysite.com/red-paint-colors

my controller:

```
class PaintController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @paint_colors = Paints.all
  end
end
```

Basic setup, I know...but I'd like to be able to inject a bunch of different paint colors for the url and `@seo_title` so that I can have a url with that reads: **www.mysite.com/blue-paint-colors** with the `@seo_title` of "Blue Paint Colors".

There's dozens of colors, is there a way I can just make a list of the colors and have a page dynamically created for each color?  So basically I'd have **www.mysite.com/blue-paint-colors**, **www.mysite.com/yellow-paint-colors**, **www.mysite.com/green-paint-colors**, etc??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you want to display dynamic content ya dynamic page like ww.mysite.com/green-paint-colors then automatically create green-paint-colors page or display only this page data.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have the chance to try this code yet, but I think it could be helpful.

In your `routes.rb` file:

```
ARRAY_OF_COLORS.each do |color|
  get "#{color}-paint-colors", to => "paint#index", color: color
end
```

In your `PaintController`:

```
def index
  color = params[:color]
  # Stuff here
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do it in the `show` view than in the `index` view. Then you could use [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem to customize the url. The `:slug` can then be a combination of the color with the static part `-paint-colors`.

In terms of bulk uploading colors: I would take a look at [CSV Imports](https://gorails.com/episodes/intro-to-importing-from-csv).